# Wordpress Next Prev outside of loop not looping through same Category

Tags: php, wordpress, user-interface, navigation

I've got a next post/prev post link outside of the loop (it's in the `footer.php`) which won't accept the command to only show posts in the same category as the current post you are viewing.

The code is:

```
<section class="navigation">

    <?php $posts = query_posts($query_string); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="left">

            <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Prev', TRUE); ?>

        </div><!-- left -->

        <div class="right">

            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next', TRUE); ?>

        </div><!-- right -->

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   

</section><!-- navigation -->
```

Presumably its because the loop above is self contained and doesn't know what the current category of the `single.php` is?

How would I get the code above to show posts in the same Category only, outside of the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the know what the current category of the current post, for that write this code :

```
//Get the active post's category

 $category = get_the_category();
 $cat = $category[0]->cat_ID;

//Run Loop on Posts of Specific Category

<?php query_posts('cat='.$cat.''); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="left">

       <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Prev', TRUE); ?>

</div><!-- left -->

<div class="right">

       <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next', TRUE); ?>

</div><!-- right -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: That wont works as they have to be inside a loop to work in the first place. Plus, it defaults to false. I'll try it though.

Comment: The format of the link `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next', TRUE); ?>` are correct. The TRUE should keep the next post within the same category. I'm pretty sure I need to do something to the loop.

Comment: @Victor : I Update my answer again

Comment: Well. I updated WP install and now the origional code I posted is working. Thanks for your help @FÔx Gênki and sorry.